# Handling Symbolic Matrices in R as in Matlab

Tags: r, matlab, matrix-multiplication, symbolic-math

I am failing to appropriately work with a Symbolic Matrix in R, with both rSymPy and Ryacas. In Matlab this is easy. **I am looking for suggestions how to do this in R and get a similar output as in Matlab**. To do this in Matlab I need the 'Symbolic Toolbox'.

In this example I wish to generate a Symbolic transition probability matrix "P", which is say 5 x 5, and has elements P11, P12,..., P55. I then want to use this matrix for multiplication (with itself and other matrices) and potentially perform also other operations.

**(1) Matlab - Generate Symbolic Matrix -> OK**

```
P = sym('P%d%d', [5 5])
```

**(1) R - Get Symbolic Matrix -> OK**

```
library(rSymPy)
P<-matrix(nrow=5, ncol=5)
for (i in 1:5){
  for (j in 1:5) {
P[i,j]<-paste0(Sym("P"), i, j) # tried Var("P") also
  }
}
```

then I want to mulitply these matrices.

**(2) Matlab - Multiply Symbolic Matrix  -> OK**

```
P*P
```

works just fine.

**(2) R - Multiply Symbolic Matrix -> Problem**

```
sympy("P * P")
Need Help Here!
```

does not work. Many other attempts did not work either. I need suggestions on how to do this correctly and get the same output as, for example, in (2) Matlab.

Additional Task:

**(3) Matlab - sym() each element separately -> OK**

Moreover I would ask for a suggestion how to Sym() a single element of the matrix P in R as in Matlab.

```
for i = 1:5;
    for j = 1:5;
    P = sprintf('P%d%d',i,j); 
    assignin('caller',P,sym(P));
    end;
end;
```

**(3) R - Sym() each element separately -> Problem**

```
Need Help Here!
```

Thx for all suggestions!

Comment: This works: `library(Ryacas); yacas("P := {{p11, p12}, {p21, p22}}");
yacas("PrettyForm(P*P)")`

Comment: I would consider starting with the sympy doc [here](http://docs.sympy.org/0.7.2/modules/matrices/expressions.html) and trying to wrap it in `rSymPy` ...

Answer (score 2):

When I did this recently, I ended up writing a function to convert R matrices to the format required for Python (see the 2x2 matrix given in the example on page 3 of https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rSymPy/rSymPy.pdf).

Let's first start with defining the matrix `P` in R:

```
library(rSymPy)

P<-matrix(nrow=5, ncol=5)
for (i in 1:5){
  for (j in 1:5) {
    P[i,j] = Var(paste0("P", i, j)) # Declare variable in matrix first
  }
}
```

I have just taken your code and adjusted it slightly. Specifically, for each element of the matrix `P`, create a SymPy variable for this element by doing `Var(paste0("P", i, j))`. For example, when `i = j = 1`, we will be creating the Sympy variable `P11`. The output of `Var` is the string `"P11"` which we store in `P[1,1]`.

At this time, we have defined an R matrix `P` where `P` is given by:

```
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5] 
[1,] "P11" "P12" "P13" "P14" "P15"
[2,] "P21" "P22" "P23" "P24" "P25"
[3,] "P31" "P32" "P33" "P34" "P35"
[4,] "P41" "P42" "P43" "P44" "P45"
[5,] "P51" "P52" "P53" "P54" "P55"
```

We have created a `SymPy` variable for each element of `P`, but we haven't defined the symbolic matrix as yet. This is our next step.

We define the function to convert the R matrix to Python's format:

```
# Converts matrix in R to Python's format
mat2py <- function(x){
  str = lapply(1:nrow(x), function(i) paste0(x[i,], collapse = ", "))
  str = paste0("Matrix([", paste0("[", unlist(str), "]", collapse = ", "), "])")
  return (str)
}
```

You use the above function as follows to define the symbolic matrix `P`:

```
cat(sympy(paste0("P = ", mat2py(P))), "\n")

# [P11, P12, P13, P14, P15]
# [P21, P22, P23, P24, P25]
# [P31, P32, P33, P34, P35]
# [P41, P42, P43, P44, P45]
# [P51, P52, P53, P54, P55]
```

(I am just using `cat(..., "\n")` to print the matrix nicely in R).

Finally, compute `P*P` as follows:

```
cat(sympy("P*P"), "\n")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in principle the output is what I want to see. BUT, I need to actually store and use the output afterwards. For example, I want to access each calculated element in your final expression, with P[1,1] or so... This seems to be difficult in your solution.

Comment: If you need to access elements afterward, you can do `cat(sympy("B = P*P"), "\n")` instead to define some matrix `B`, and just access the elements as `sympy("B[0,0]")`. @J_F's answer looks much simpler though.

Answer (score 2):

And this works with `rSymPy`:

```
library(rSymPy)

a1 <- Var("a1")
a2 <- Var("a2")
a3 <- Var("a3")
a4 <- Var("a4")

A <- Matrix(List(a1, a2), List(a3, a4))

A*A
#[1] "[a2*a3 + a1**2, a1*a2 + a2*a4]\n[a1*a3 + a3*a4, a2*a3 + a4**2]"
```

Comment: Thank you, I saw this example before. BUT, to me the difficulty is to actually sym() or var() all variables separately. Suppose you would do it for 1000 variables. That means typing: a1 <- Var("a1") ..... a1000<-Var("a1000"). You will get crazy. I think finding a way to do that in a loop or so is the key to the solution.

Comment: So do that ... should be no problem.