# How to obtain determinant as polynomial when matrix includes unknown values (in R)?

Tags: r, matrix, polynomials, determinants

if I have a matrix that is including variables as entries, how can I obtain the determinant? It does not seem like R can handle non-numeric entries in matrices in calculations.

for ex.

```
    z <- matrix(c(1,1,1,"d"),nrow = 2)
```

then I would want the answer to be like det(z)=d-1  i.e in as a polynomial including the variable d. 
is this possible with the "det" function in r?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39820161/handling-symbolic-matrices-in-r-as-in-matlab for handling symbolic matrices in R

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
> library(Ryacas)
> yacas("M := {{1, 1}, {1, d}}")
expression(list(list(1, 1), list(1, d)))
> yacas("Determinant(M)")
expression(d - 1)
```

However I don't know whether there's a convenient way to defined the matrix `M` directly from its value in R. Perhaps it's possible; there are some docs to check...

---

## EDIT 2020-02

With the new `Ryacas` package:

```
M <- matrix(c("1", "1", "1", "d"), nrow = 2)
yac_assign(ysym(M), "M")
yac_str("Determinant(M)")
# [1] "d-1"
```