# Symbolic matrix problem in R using rSymph

Tags: python, r, matrix-multiplication, symbolic-math

I need to perform symbolic matrix multiplication, Ry.Ry, using rSympy in R console.

```
library(rSymPy)
Ry = matrix(c("c","-s","s","c"),2,2, byrow=1); Ry
########## I convert matrix in R to Python's format
# from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39820161/handling-symbolic-matrices-in-r-as-in-matlab
# written by jav

mat2py <- function(x){
  str = lapply(1:nrow(x), function(i) 
paste0(x[i,], collapse = ", "))
  str = paste0("Matrix([", paste0("[", 
unlist(str), "]", collapse = ", "), "])")
  return (str)
}
mat2py(Ry)
cat(sympy(mat2py(Ry)), "\n")
```

got error message as follows:

> Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod",
> cl,  :    Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line
> 1, in  NameError: name 'c' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Still got error message. When I execute
cat(sympy("Ry*Ry"), "\n")

Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Z", "hasField", .jcast(x, "java/lang/Object"),  :
java.lang.NullPointerException
#################### below is the code  #############

```
library(rSymPy)
str1="c"
str2="-s"
str3="s"
str4="c"
str(str1)
P=matrix(c(str1, str2, str3, str4),2,2, byrow=1); P

Ry<-matrix(nrow=2, ncol=2)
for (i in 1:2){
for (j in 1:2) {
Ry[i,j] = paste0(P[i,j]) # Declare variable in matrix 
first
   }
 }
Ry

mat2py <- function(x){
str = lapply(1:nrow(x), function(i) paste0(x[i,], 
collapse = ", "))
str = paste0("Matrix([", paste0("[", unlist(str), "]", 
collapse = ", "), "])")
return (str)
}

 mat2py(Ry)
 cat(sympy(mat2py(Ry)), "\n")
 cat(sympy("Ry*Ry"), "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the documentation of rSymPy - have you already tried to use this code?
I am not familiar with the rSymPy package, but I think it is necessary to declare your variables `c`, `-s` and `s` as SymPy variables.

```
library(rSymPy)
# create a SymPy variable called c
sympy("var('c')")
# create a SymPy variable called -s
sympy("var('-s')")
# create a SymPy variable called s
sympy("var('s')")

# Matrices are stored row by row (unlike R matrices)
cat(sympy("Ry = Matrix([[c,-s], [s,c]])"), "\n")
cat(sympy("Ry*Ry"), "\n")
```